# how to create a method that will call URL's From a list with flutter

Tags: flutter, google-api, flutter-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

I am working with google books in my flutter project.
im trying to create a method that that will call the diffrent books URL's that i have stored in a List and call the list back using a future builder.

The list look somthing like this:

```
List<String> toBeReadBooksList = ['https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=1086782593+isbn'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it a way that similar to this:

```dart
final url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=1086782593+isbn';
final response = await http.get(url)

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // Here you need to parse data from response, you should replace it with your realization:
  return Data.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load data from $url');
}
```

You can read more about how to work with requests and responses to/from the Network in [Official Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data).

Answer (score 0):

Import url_launcher plugin `import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';`
and in your `pubspec.yaml` dependecies `url_launcher: ^5.7.10`

add this and call it to open the selected url

```
_launchURL() async {
 const url = toBeReadBooksList[0];//your list url
 if (await canLaunch(url)) {
   await launch(url);
  } 
 else {
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
 }
```